# Logic app trigger when blob is created showing error

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-triggers

I have created a logic app and I want it to trigger when a new blob is added to a storage account. As soon as I add this trigger, the following error comes, its not very descriptive and not sure which permissions is it not seeing.

Please check your account info and/or permissions and try again. Details: This request is not authorized to perform this operation.

I am following instructions mentioned here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azureblobstorage#add-blob-storage-trigger

HTTP trigger works but then then storage connection step fails again. I am not sure what account info or permissions is not given.

[image]

Also, when I try to create a new connection . I am still seeing the same error.
[image: Connection string error]

Also, I noticed that storage account and logic app cant be in the same region. I kept them separate by having storage app in West US 2 and logic app in West US 1.

I am following the instructions in this article too. But have the same issue.
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/integrations-on-azure/access-storage-accounts-behind-firewalls-from-logic-apps-within/ba-p/1997801

Here is a screenshot of that.  Http connection works but Azure Blob storage connection does not.

[image]

Comment: Could you please check which role(s) of the storage account be assigned to your account ?

Comment: Yes, the logic app is assigned a Storage Blob Data Contributor role.

Comment: You mentioned a link of "access storage account behind firewall", may I know if your storage is behind firewall ? Or your storage without firewall, just refer to the document ?

Comment: And may I know if you use virtual network for your storage ?

Comment: @HuryShen good questions, how can I check if the storage account is behind a firewall?  Pretty sure we are not using virtual network for the storage, if there is a way for me to check that please let me know.  I dont have all privileges and permissions but I can check.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have posted your query in Q&A. I have posted answer in the [Q&A thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/359193/logic-app-trigger-when-blob-is-created-showing-err.html?childToView=359555#answer-359555).

Comment: Thanks @MayankBargali-MSFT. I did mention in my post that storage account is in West US 2 and logic app is in West US region so both are in different regions.  And  I also checked the allow trusted msft services to access storage account.